# Q-Chem gives "Hessian Appears to have all zero or negative eigenvalues" error when calculating Frequencies

Tags: software-assistance, vibrations, q-chem

I have troubles with obtaining spectra for selected molecules in different DFT functionals.

I calculate IR spectra for my target molecules (gold complexes with C/H/N/O/S/Au composition) to find how different levels of theory fit experimental data. In most cases everything looks fine, but for some unknown reason for two of them I have issues. In both cases the problem is the same: after geometry optimization is finished and I move to frequency job the Hessian appeared to have only -nan values:

```
Hessian of the SCF Energy
            1           2           3           4           5           6
    1        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan
    2        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan
    3        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan
    4        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan
    5        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan
    6        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan
```

And I get an error message after that:

```
    # Finishing finite difference calculation for IDERIV #
 ######################################################
 ######################################################

  ***ERROR*** Hessian Appears to have all zero or negative eigenvalues
```

For one molecule it is with B3LYP, for the other one with BPBE. Same molecules in other functionals work smoothly.

I had the same problem a few times for other complexes, but it was always resolved when I distorted the initial structure and re-performed optimization+frequency calculation. Calculation of frequencies alone with a given structure does not solve the issue either.

What might be the reason and possible solution for that?

Comment: -nan implies you might be dividing by zero or dividing by inf (both can give undefined results).  Are you doing analytical frequency calculations or finite difference/numerical.

Comment: @TristanMaxson, This one is "Calculating analytic Hessian of the SCF energy".

Comment: My recomedation is to start with geometries near a minimum. I normally do a geometric optimization using Molecular Mechanics, then semi-empiric and finally DFT. Negative frequencies indicates that the geometry is far from equilibrium.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try semi-empirical first and see if it helps with further DFT job.

Comment: @DmitryEremin How did it go? Did the suggestion to try semi-empirical first work?

Comment: @NikeDattani, actually not as I expected, thus did not post an answer. I have a metal framework, which geometry is pre-optimized and constrained. With this constraint result is always the same, but calculation converged (in much longer time) as I removed it. I am thinking of the problem in general. I will have to post another question on this regard soon.

Comment: It's impossible to say what the exact issue is without more information. Can you post an input file? What version of Q-Chem are you using?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened with clarification from the OP or if another user would like to provide an answer.